# Determine flyway variables from earlier SQL step

Tags: flyway

I'd like to use flyway for a DB update with the situation that an DB already exists with productive data in it. The problem I'm looking at now (and I did not find a nice solution yet), is the following:

1. There is an existing DB table with numeric IDs, e.g.

   create table objects ( obj_id number, ...)
2. There is a sequence "obj_seq" to allocate new obj_ids
3. During my DB migration I need to introduce a few new objects, hence I need new
   object IDs. However I do not know at development time, what ID
   numbers these will be
4. There is a DB trigger which later references these IDs. To improve performance I'd like to avoid determine the actual IDs every time the trigger runs but rather put the IDs directly into the trigger

Example (very simplified) of what I have in mind:

1. insert into objects (obj_id, ...) values (obj_seq.nextval, ...)
2. select obj_seq.currval from dual

   -> store this in variable "newID"
3. create trigger on some_other_table
   when new.id = newID
   ...

Now, is it possible to dynamically determine/use such variables? I have seen the flyway placeholders but my understanding is that I cannot set them dynamically as in the example above.

I could use a Java-based migration script and do whatever string magic I like - so, that would be a way of doing it, but maybe there is a more elegant way using SQL?

Many thx!!

tge

Answer (score 0):

If the table you are updating contains only reference data, get rid of the sequence and assign the IDs manually.

If it contains a mix of reference and user data, you need to select the id based on values in other columns.

Comment: Mmm, I cannot remove the sequence easily, is used elsewhere.
Finding the actual IDs based on other data is possible - but how do I get them into the trigger code?
Actually I'm still not convinced whether this is the right way at all - I just wanted to avoid doing this in the actual trigger every time again ...